# Get value of timestamp column value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a sql query to retrieve the records from date range of a month but I did not get the result. Below is my query that I tried to run.

```
SELECT uid FROM sessions WHERE TIMESTAMP >= '2021-10-01 00:00:00' AND TIMESTAMP < '2021-10-31 00:00:00'
```

timestamp column contain value in numeric
[see link:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O33Sv.png)

CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
`uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The users.uid corresponding to a session, or 0 for anonymous user.',
`sid` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL COMMENT 'A session ID (hashed). The value is generated by Drupal''s session handlers.',
`hostname` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The IP address that last used this session ID (sid).',
`timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The Unix timestamp when this session last requested a page. Old records are purged by PHP automatically.',
`session` longblob COMMENT 'The serialized contents of $_SESSION, an array of name/value pairs that persists across page requests by this session ID. Drupal loads $_SESSION from here at the start of each request and saves it at the end.',
PRIMARY KEY (`sid`),
KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='Drupal''s session handlers read and write into the sessions…'

Comment: .. AND TIMESTAMP < '2021-11-01 00:00:00'

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-10-01 00:00:00')` could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://database.guide/unix_timestamp-examples-mysql/) to convert the datetime strings to unix timestamp numbers

```
SELECT uid 
FROM sessions 
WHERE `TIMESTAMP` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-10-01 00:00:00')
  AND `TIMESTAMP` <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-10-31 23:59:59')
```

Comment: This also not working

Comment: And if the name is backticked?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should'nt use 'TIMESTAMP' as a column name. But I think if only one example. If not, change it.

You have some options.

## Using BETWEEN command

```
SELECT uid FROM sessions WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2021-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-10-31 00:00:00'
```

## Using MONTH and YEAR

```
SELECT uid FROM sessions WHERE MONTH(TIMESTAMP) = MONTH('2021-10-01 00:00:00') AND YEAR(TIMESTAMP) = YEAR('2021-10-01 00:00:00')
```

Comment: timestamp column contain value in numeric see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O33Sv.png

Comment: The timestamp format is 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'. Your column have another time of values. Try to check this in your table structure.

Comment: time stamp is 10 digit numeric value. 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' is a datetime type

Comment: Yes. Your column has another type that I can't understand what is, to be honest.

Comment: I send table creation in question. please have a look

Comment: You use int ( integer 11 ) to timestamp. See this link to see some useful examples for you. 

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx


Try create something like this :
CREATE TABLE test_timestamp (
    t1  TIMESTAMP
);

Comment: To sum up change timestamp int(11) to timestamp timestamp, for example

Comment: But you really should consider change the name of column ;)